# Hide tooltip for all page controls Silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

Recently, I started to work with Silverlight 5. I need to implement the possibility to optionaly hide tooltips for all controls which present on page.

For example, a page contains a group of buttons:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=VerifyDocCommand}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Source={StaticResource Trans}, Path=ToolTipSaveButton}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Documents.CurrentItem, FallbackValue=null}" Style="{StaticResource VerifyButton}"/>
...
```

I create the following style for `ToolTip`:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ShowTooltips, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConv}}"/>
    </Style>
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

But Tooltip of the button above is still visible, even if I use this style:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Style>
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

Could you please to advise how to I can implement this functionality?

Comment: try set tooltip property = "" ?

Comment: try set tooltip property ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a convenient way offered by the Silverlight `ToolTipService` itself.

I can think of two possible solutions:

**First solution:** Introduce a coding rule for your project that basically says:

> all ToolTip Bindings shall either use the `SwitchOffConverter` (if their source is the DataContext) or have a `SwitchOffTextResources` object as their Source

And use as follows:

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding VerifyDocument}"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=LocalizedText.VerifyDocument_ToolTip,
        Source={StaticResource DeactivatableUiText}}"/>
```

or

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding VerifyDocument}"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=VerifyDocument.Description,
        Converter={StaticResource ToolTipSwitcher}}"/>
```

with

```
<Resources>
    <SwitchOffUiTextResources x:Key="DeactivatableUiText"/>
    <SwitchOffConverter x:Key="ToolTipSwitcher"/>
</Resources>
```

and

```
public static class ToolTipSwitch
{
    private static bool s_isToolTipActivated = true;
    public static bool IsToolTipActivated
    {
        get { return s_isToolTipActivated; }
        set
        {
            if (s_isToolTipActivated != value)
            {
                s_isToolTipActivated = value;
                RaiseIsToolTipActivatedChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void RaiseIsToolTipActivatedChanged()
    {
        var handlers = IsToolTipActivatedChanged;
        if (handlers != null) handlers();
    }

    public static event Action IsToolTipActivatedChanged;
}

public class SwitchOffConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ToolTipSwitch.IsToolTipActivated ? value : null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public class SwitchOffUiTextResources : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SwitchOffUiTextResources()
    {
        ToolTipSwitch.IsToolTipActivatedChanged += OnIsToolTipActivatedChanged;
    }

    private void OnIsToolTipActivatedChanged()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged( "LocalizedText" );
    }

    private UiTextResources m_localizedText = new UiTextResources();

    public UiTextResources LocalizedText
    {
        get { return ToolTipSwitch.IsToolTipActivated ? m_localizedStrings : null; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Second solution:** Write your own `DeactivatableToolTipService` as a thin wrapper around the Silverlight `ToolTipService` and only use your own service. If the service is deactivated just set all tooltips to null.
I would totally go that second approach.

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding VerifyDocument}"
    DeactivatableToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding ...anything...}"/>
```

Comment: I tried to use SwitchOffConverter and it works fine! Thank you!